# NSUserDefaults work different on Iphone and Simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I'm using NSUserDefaults to save an integer on another view controller so that when this one is pushed I know which image to use. For some reason the simulator only uses image1 while my phone only uses image2. What can I do?

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"key"] == 1){

    leftStill = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];

}

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"key"] == 2) {

    leftStill = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];

}

[imageView setImage:leftStill];
```

Comment: Your code is telling you that on the simulator the value of the key is 1, whereas it is 2 on the device. You may have a bug in your code where you are setting these keys, but you didn't post that so how can we tell?

Comment: No the integer is coming out correctly when I use NSLog to check, its only the images

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Something else is going on then. For example "image1.png" and "image2.png" are somehow not what you think they are. You could verify this by putting `NSLog` just before you assign to `leftStill`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you call `- (BOOL)synchronize;` after setting the value in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Read to documentation on NSUerDefaults. Get used to reading them so it becomes second nature. You'll find your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting with a nil/unallocated leftImage and imageView before this code block?

Since you're testing an integer value, I wonder if the following code might not work better for you, potentially avoiding not only the two readings of the value that your code is currently doing, which might be the cause of the issue, but also the use of the intermediary holder leftImage itself:

```
switch([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"key"]) {
  case 1:
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
    break;
  case 2:
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like the following when you store the value in NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setInteger:1 forKey:@"key"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

The synchronize does happen periodically on its own but you have no guarantee when it will happen.  So I usually synchronize any time I am setting a value for a key in NSUserDefaults.

You may want to also consider something better suited for the task you are trying to accomplish, like using prepareForSegue.